# How to add reverb to the snare only in superior drummer?

Tags: production

Is there a way to add reverb to just the snare in superior drummer?

I am using Nuendo and if I add reverb as an insert, it is added to the whole track, making the bass drums and toms sound a little awful.

I was wondering if there is a way to add reverb to just the snare drum.

Comment: Can you copy just the snare channel as a separate track and add a 100% wet reverb to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard way to do this is to use a separate track for each drum, so you can tweak each one to your specific needs, whether that be to use reverb, EQ or whatever.

[This Steinberg forum thread](https://www.steinberg.net/forums/viewtopic.php?f=181&t=40126) indicates how to load SD as a rack, rather than a single plug-in:

> Just press F11 which brings up the rack (or Devices/VST Instruments via the dropdown menus). Click on an empty slot in the rack and load Superior Drummer.

Having it in a track also allows you to automate control of settings over time, as you mentioned in [your other question.](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/48958/104)

After you import superior drummer, and at the vst instruments window, click on the icon that looks like an arrow located left of the VST name ('superior drummer' in our case) and select 'activate all outputs'.

Then go to the Superior Drummer mixer and send every output that corresponds to the snare to another output (out 2 for example). To find which outputs I need to send I 'solo' the snare. Then you can add reverb as an insert for that channel only.

Comment: This is how I add Superior drummer, and yes, I have it in a track. I don't know how to add reverb to just the snare drum from then on. (and also I don't know how to answer my other question)

Comment: You need to have each drum in a different track, not all in the same one.

Comment: I'll try do do that later today - maybe grab some screenshots (I use Cubase, but I don't use SD - so it will just have to be showing how automation works)